# Java Generics Wildcard vs Typed Generics usage

Tags: java, generics

I am reading through the following section in the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

It starts off by saying that the following code produces an error due to the fact that a capture cannot be converted to an Object so the `set` method cannot confirm that Object is of type capture#1:

```
import java.util.List;

public class WildcardError {

    void foo(List<?> i) {
        i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}
```

I *somewhat* understand the reasoning behind this. i.get returns an Object, and the compiler cannot determine if the object is of type capture#1 so it cannot match it to the 2nd argument in a typesafe way.

It then recommends using the following code to make this method work:

```
public class WildcardFixed {

    void foo(List<?> i) {
        fooHelper(i);
    }


    // Helper method created so that the wildcard can be captured
    // through type inference.
    private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l) {
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }

}
```

I *somewhat* understand why this code works as well, in this code, `l.get` is guaranteed to be of type T, so it can be passed as an argument of type T.

What I don't understand is why you couldn't just use a method like this, with no helper:

```
class GenericsTest {
    static <K> void bar(List<K> l) {
        l.set(0, l.get(l.size() - 1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        bar(lst);
        System.out.println(lst); // [4, 3, 2, 4]
    }
}
```

i.e. if you're going to use type inference, why not just use explicit typed generics over a wildcard and a helper function? Is there any advantage to using wildcards in this scenario? In which cases would you actually prefer to use a wildcard over a typed generic?

Comment: What does `static <K> void` mean, according to you?

Comment: @Mike To me, it means that K is a type parameter that only applies to the scope of the method. Java uses type inference to figure out what K is supposed to be at runtime. In the example shown I pass in an instance of List<Integer> so the compiler infers K to be Integer. K can be any reference type, and reference types extend from Object, so I consider K to be just another way of writing <?> explicitly in this case.

Comment: @Mike I don't know...it seems to be the same as a regular void method. I didn't know K had anything to do with the return. I'm just using the syntax from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your `fooHelper` and `bar` use the same types. The indices are just different (and `static` vs instance, but that doesn't matter either).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The question is essentially why would you ever create a method that uses <?> over something that uses a typed generic like <K>? It seems to me that they both have the same level of type safety and both can handle all reference types, but using a typed generic lets you do more without the compiler complaining.

Comment: There's no great difference. According to Effective Java 2nd edition (page 140) the version using a wildcard is preferable because it's easier to understand, as it's clear that you can pass in any List without a type parameter confusing the issue.

Comment: You might check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796921/java-generics-wildcard-vs-typed-generics-usage?rq=1 for some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `void foo(List<?> i)` and `void <K> foo(List<K> i)` both accept the exact same set of arguments -- assuming you don't explicitly specify a `K` on the generic method case, any argument that can be passed to one function signature can be passed to the other, and vice versa. So to "outside code", both signatures are equally useful.

Given that they are equivalent, the one that has fewer type parameters is simpler, and should always be preferred. When presenting a public API to outside code, you should always present it in the simplest form, only having the minimal type stuff necessary to make it safe. The type `List<?>` is sufficient to express that it can take any type of `List`, so that is what we should use.

We happen to use the type parameter `K` internally to solve some generics issues, but this is just an unfortunate internal implementation detail that outside code does not need to care about. Therefore, we should hide this ugliness and wrap it in a nicer function signature when making a public API.

In addition to abstraction purposes, another reason why you may want a particular signature is if it overrides a superclass method that has that signature. You cannot add type parameters when overriding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example you mention in the tutorial refers to handling cases when you need to accept parameters with unbound wildcards `<?>`. This may be the case when interacting with legacy code or extending an existing class with such a wildcard type.

Mostly you will use things like `<T extends U>` or `<? extends T>` when you need flexibility but don't want to sacrifice type checking.